# Unable to compile Protocol Buffers (protobuf) examples in MSVS 2022 on Windows 10

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compiler-errors, windows-10, protocol-buffers

I'm trying to compile a protobuf example from here: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/cpptutorial.
My system configuration:

- Windows 10 Pro,
- Visual studion 2022 (Community Ed.) with C++ Package for Desktop Development,
- Protobuf v3.20.0 (Latest Version).
  I've done the following steps:

1. Compiled protobuf from the source code, successfully ran tests, and got the *install* folder with the files: *bin*, *cmake*, *include*, *lib*
2. After generating .cpp and .h files using *protoc.exe*, I added them to the VS project and also included *libprotobuf.lib*.Then, I specified path to the *include* folder in the project properties -> VC++ Directories -> Include Directories.
3. While building console application in VS 2022, I was getting a lot of errors, which impossible to fit in in this post, here is some of them:

```
Error (active)  E2614   nonvirtual function cannot be declared with 'final' modifier    ConsoleApplication1 C:\Cpp_Projects\Protobuf\Demo\Project\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\addressbook.pb.h  619 
Error (active)  E2614   nonvirtual function cannot be declared with 'final' modifier    ConsoleApplication1 C:\Cpp_Projects\Protobuf\Demo\Project\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\addressbook.pb.h  633 
Error (active)  E2614   nonvirtual function cannot be declared with 'final' modifier    ConsoleApplication1 C:\Cpp_Projects\Protobuf\Demo\Project\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\addressbook.pb.h  635 
Error (active)  E0393   pointer to incomplete class type "tutorial::Person" is not allowed  ConsoleApplication1 C:\Cpp_Projects\Protobuf\Demo\Project\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1.cpp   12  
Error (active)  E0393   pointer to incomplete class type "tutorial::Person" is not allowed  ConsoleApplication1 C:\Cpp_Projects\Protobuf\Demo\Project\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1.cpp   16  
Error (active)  E0393   pointer to incomplete class type "tutorial::Person" is not allowed  ConsoleApplication1 C:\Cpp_Projects\Protobuf\Demo\Project\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1.cpp   22  
Error (active)  E0393   pointer to incomplete class type "tutorial::Person" is not allowed  ConsoleApplication1 C:\Cpp_Projects\Protobuf\Demo\Project\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1.cpp   33  
Error (active)  E0470   the global scope has no tag named "TableStruct_addressbook_2eproto" ConsoleApplication1 C:\Cpp_Projects\Protobuf\Demo\Project\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\addressbook.pb.h  263 
Error (active)  E0470   the global scope has no tag named "TableStruct_addressbook_2eproto" ConsoleApplication1 C:\Cpp_Projects\Protobuf\Demo\Project\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\addressbook.pb.h  512 
Error (active)  E0470   the global scope has no tag named "TableStruct_addressbook_2eproto" ConsoleApplication1 C:\Cpp_Projects\Protobuf\Demo\Project\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\addressbook.pb.h  671 
Error (active)  E0077   this declaration has no storage class or type specifier ConsoleApplication1 C:\Cpp_Projects\Protobuf\Demo\Project\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\addressbook.pb.h  37  
Error (active)  E0077   this declaration has no storage class or type specifier ConsoleApplication1 C:\Cpp_Projects\Protobuf\Demo\Project\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\addressbook.pb.h  59  
Error (active)  E0077   this declaration has no storage class or type specifier ConsoleApplication1 C:\Cpp_Projects\Protobuf\Demo\Project\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\addressbook.pb.h  63  
Error (active)  E0077   this declaration has no storage class or type specifier ConsoleApplication1 C:\Cpp_Projects\Protobuf\Demo\Project\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\addressbook.pb.h  358 
Error (active)  E0077   this declaration has no storage class or type specifier ConsoleApplication1 C:\Cpp_Projects\Protobuf\Demo\Project\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\addressbook.pb.h  607 
Error (active)  E0077   this declaration has no storage class or type specifier ConsoleApplication1 C:\Cpp_Projects\Protobuf\Demo\Project\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\addressbook.pb.h  1053
```

NB: I'm only a beginner in C++, so I understand very little about the compilation process, how to setup it in VS 2022, and what errors are relevant to include in the post.

Comment: The only solution I could find: instead of using MSVS compilator, I succesfully compiled protobuf with MinGW-w64 compiler for Windows.